# What does it mean that a user is unregistered?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

In [this user profile](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/271607/do-not-reinstate-monica) after their name is the tag "Unregistered".

What does it mean, and what is different in comparison with a common (registered) user?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not need to register in order to participate here (on other Stack Exchange sites it may be different); just leaving a display name and email address is enough. You can test this yourself by opening a private browser window (or another browser) and start writing a question:

[image]

The system will remember you through cookies, but once you clear those, *you're effectively logged out forever*, meaning you can't edit your posts, reply to comments or upvote. Unregistered users are also not shown in [the list of users](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/).

For more information, see the [questions about 'unregistered users'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unregistered-users) on Meta Stack Exchange.